# Easy way to manage table data visually

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access

I am working on project in economy where I need to manage large data in linked tables, with many foreign keys.
I have a few years of experience as Oracle DBA so I can manage all that without problem,
But I need to be able to share the data with others that have no knowledge in databasing,
There for I need to get them some graphic way to show the data.
Toad does all what I need and much more, but the program is too complicated for my needs.

Instead of wasting time on writing a program in C# that manages the data, I am looking for a good program that:

1. Shows Main table/view data with option to filter/group/order with drop-box options
2. Selects a row and shows data in linked tables by the selected row's data
3. Makes report/data pages of my selected rows that I can adjust and print. (I know it's a bigger request)

In Addition, what is the most fit and easy DB for it? I worked only with Oracle but it's sure too much for that, so MySql? Access (I tried first to do all that in Access program but It's just too hard to adjust forms and so, and in the end you cannot make a publish version.

And the tables will be with start_date and finish_date that follow each other for same ID,
But I don't think it will be a problem that I can maximum make view that shows only the last one. (BTW, what is the name of such table, I never knew that)

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: Are you talking about maintaining a log of changes to records in other tables, so you know when every record was ever created, updated, or deleted and what information was in that record at that time?  If so, I hear that most commonly referred to as an audit table.

Comment: @coge.soft, I don't talk about additional table that log the changes, what you talk about is like the way oracle do rollups and hot backup. What I talk about is a table that each time you cahnge data for this ID, it's not edit the row, instead do for this row end_date=sysdate and then make new row with the update row that have start_date=sysdate and have end_date null or max_date, This way you can in the most easy way to see without work what was the status in any past date/time. and in this work if you delete row it's simply put end_date=sysdate without new row. I don't think I invented it.

Comment: Yes.  That is what I'm trying to talk about.  Most DBMSs feature table-level triggers that will execute upon an insert, update, or delete and allow easy access to the original and the changing values.  You can use these together to `INSERT` the old and new values (along with current sysdate) to keep an audit log.  Whatever DBMS you end up choosing, do a google search for "(MySQL, Oracle, etc) audit table".

Comment: @coge.soft, Yes I know what audit table is and I'm talk on complete diffrent kind of table that save the records with primery key of ID+t.start so each time the row has changed it's actuly not changed but make a new row, don't know the name of that kind of table storing. anyway this is not the main point, still stuck in the big problem :*(

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Tableau http://www.tableausoftware.com

It will let users view the data many different ways, makes great visualizations and works with most databases. It's a read-only tool, so it's perfect for safe reporting, but you'll need to couple it with something else if you want your users to make changes to the data.

You can define a connection in Tableau that sets up the relationships for users that don't understand foreign keys and the like. Or make views that hide those details, of course, regardless of the tool you choose.